# Why does Google maps (in terrain mode) space thier topo lines 80 feet apart?

Tags: topography

Is 80 feet some sort of standard?

[image]

Comment: It does so in the United States, but not everywhere.  For example, it uses [20 metre in Switzerland](https://www.google.ch/maps/@46.0516137,7.7862577,15z/data=!5m1!1e4).

Answer (score 5):

Based on USGS (Department of the Interior – United States Geological Survey) toopgraphic maps, where on a 7.5 min Quadrangle map, the contour interval is commonly 40 feet.  Larger maps 15 min to 1'-2' maps the interval is commonly 80-100 feet.

All maps of the United States are commonly sourced from USGS based maps.  I am certain Google or Google's map provider is using USGS base maps.

Reference:
http://geology.isu.edu/geostac/Field_Exercise/topomaps/vert_scale.htm